# How to get exact kafka topic names when the consumer is subscribed to regex topic pattern?

Tags: apache-kafka

Assume a kafka consumer is subscribed to regex pattern. We want to show metrics information in UI and for that exact topic names are required. Please let me know if we have any APIs for this.

Comment: This works. Thanks Felipe. In the partitionsAssigned method I can get the list of all the topics that this consumer group is listening to.